# What's the best way to pass field arguments (e.g. paging parameters) to a deferred `Fetcher`?

Tags: scala, graphql, sangria

Below is an example of how I'm currently handling deferred field arguments.

A `Parent` class contains a deferred `Page` of `Child` objects. The paging parameters for the children are defined on the `children` field. I need to be able to pass the paging parameters, along with the parent's id, to the deferred `Fetcher`, so I bundle them up in a temporary `DeferredChildInput` object, along with the parent's id, and pass them to the `Fetcher`. A corresponding `DeferredChildResult` returns the result of the query (the `Page[Child]`) and the `DeferredChildInput` (use in the `HasId`).

Question is, is there a better way to pass field arguments and parent id to the deferred `Fetcher`?

```
case class Page[T](
  data: Seq[T],
  pageNumber: Int,
  pageSize: Int,
  totalRecords: Long
)

case class Parent(
  id: Long,
  children: Page[Children] // this field is deferred
)

case class Child(
  id: Long
  parentId: Long
)

// the field's query parameters
case class DeferredChildInput(
  parentId: Long,
  pageNumber: Int,
  pageSize: Int
)

// used to temporarily hold the result of the deferred resolution
case class DeferredChildResult(
  input: DeferredChildInput // this is used to resolve the HasId check
  page: Page[Child] // this is what we really want
)

trait ChildService {
  def getChildrenByParentId(
    parentId: Long,
    pageNumber: Int,
    pageSize: Int
  ): Page[Child]
}

val childFetcher: Fetcher[MyContext, DeferredChildResult, DeferredChildResult, DeferredChildInput] = Fetcher {
    (ctx: MyContext, inputs: Seq[DeferredChildInput]) =>
      val futures = inputs.map { input =>
        ctx.childService.getChildrenByParentId(
          input.parentId,
          input.pageNumber,
          input.pageSize
        ).map { childPage =>
          DeferredChildResult(input, childPage)
        }
      }

    Future.sequence {
      futures
    }
  }(HasId(_.input))
}

val ChildObjectType = derivedObjectType[Unit, Child]()

val ParentObjectType = deriveObjectType[Unit, Parent](
  ReplaceField(
    fieldName = "children",
    field = Field(
      name = "children",
      fieldType = PageType(childObjectType),
      arguments = List(
        Argument(
          name = "pageNumber",
          argumentType = IntType
        ), Argument(
          name = "pageSize",
          argumentType = IntType,
        )
      ),
      resolve = ctx => {
        // bundle the field/query parameters into a single input object
        val input = DeferredChildInput(
          parentId = ctx.value.id,
          pageNumber = ctx.args[Int]("pageNumber"),
          pageSize = ctx.args[Int]("pageSize")
        )

        DeferredValue(childFetcher.defer(input)).map { results =>
          results.page
        }
      }
    )
  )
)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this scenario, you don't really benefit from using fetchers, it just increases the complexity of data fetching mechanism. For example, it is quite unlikely that results would be cached and reused. You are also resolving each `DeferredChildInput` separately which defeats the main purpose of fetchers (which is to batch the data fetching, where data for all `inputs` is fetched in a single request/DB interaction).

I would recommend avoiding using fetchers altogether in this scenario and fetch the page data directly from resolve function. Fetchers don't really support pagination. In some scenarios, it might be viable to fetch the IDs of entities in a resolve function and then use fetcher to fetch the entity data based on the already known list of IDs. But as far as I can tell, it is not the case in your scenario.

Comment: If you fetched it in the resolve method, wouldn't you lose the benefit of optionally fetching data only when requested? In this case if someone only wanted a list of parent ids, the service would only be fetching parents from the database, and wouldn't need to fetch any children.

Comment: My example wasn't good. I should have allowed for fetching the `Child` pages for multiple `Parent`s, so `ChildService. getChildrenByParentId` should have been `ChildService.getChildrenByParentIds` (plural) and that should have returned a `Seq[Page[Child]]` not just a `Page[Child]`. That would have allowed for one call to the server to fetch the `children` for more than one `Parent`.

Comment: I should have also avoided "paging" as the example, let's say we're just filtering the `children` by some arguments passed to the `Field`. Does it makes sense to use an "input" object to pass the filtering arguments to the `Fetcher` or is there a better way that I'm missing?

Comment: In this case relations might be helpful. Maybe you could check this discussion, i think it is related https://github.com/sangria-graphql/sangria/issues/280 Though in general you can't really parametrize the deferred value when you are using fetchers. So adding pagination or more or less complex filter criterias does not really work with fetchers (though you can implement all these things if you will create your own `DeferredResolver`).

Answer (score 0):

Also when using resolvers and returning N parent objects you would end up with N+1 fetches for every child object which is much slower than fetching n pages of child objects and grouping by the parent object id.